# Creating variable of flexible data type in JAVA

Tags: java, generics

I have `class A` , `class B` and `class C`.

In `class C`,i am declaring the variable like:

```
private A a;
private B b;
private ? thirdVariable;
```

I want to declare the third variable whose data type **can be of A or B**.
So that i can *assign* this variable *either the value of `a` or `b`* as per my wish.

Comment: `private Object thirdVariable`...?

Comment: What are `A` and `B`? Are they related in some way?

Comment: @Sweeper i don't want to create super class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `Polymorphism` with an `(abstract) class` or an `Interface`

- `Interface` :

  ```
  public Interface Parent{        }

  public class A implements Parent {        }

  public class B implements Parent {        }

  public class C {
      private A a;
      private B b;
      private Parent thirdVariable;
  }
  ```
- `(abstract) class` : the abstract is optionnal and depend of the design and the functionnalities that you have to make

  ```
  public (abstract) class Parent{        }

  public class A extends Parent {        }

  public class B extends Parent {        }

  public class C {
      private A a;
      private B b;
      private Parent thirdVariable;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that if there is no relation between A & B. If you want to do that then you should Interface/Class that will be extended by A & B.

```
class X{}

class A extends X{
}

class B extends X{
}

private X thirdVariable;
```

If you really want to use Generic then Make your use a generic constructor in class C and then pass the object of `A/B` according to the generic like below.

```
class C<T> {
    private T thirdVariable;

    C(T t) {
        thirdVariable = t;
    }
}
```

When you create the object of C then you can specify and pass the type of object like below.

```
    A a = new A();
    C<A> c1 = new C<A>(a);
    B b = new B();
    C<B> c2 = new C<B>(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a (possibly abstract) superclass (let's call it `class X`) and make both `A` and `B` extend from it. Then, your third variable can be declared as:

```
private X thirdVariable;
```

Similarly, you could create an interface (let's call it `interface Y`) and make both `A` and `B` implement it. Then, your third variable can be declared as:

```
private Y thirdVariable;
```

So basically you want to put polymorphism to good use, because generics are not flexible enough to express a type relationship like the one you want.

Comment: I don't want to create the super class , can we use generics in some way ?

Comment: @ShivendraGupta generics are not flexible enough to express a type relationship as the one you want. Consider my second option then, using an interface.

Comment: You need to achieve polymorphism, you pretty much have to. Generics are different, that is about being type agnostic.